# Prefix tree implementation

Tags: c, prefix-tree

I am working on storing a list of cities(read from a file) with their corresponding latitude and longitude values. At the end of each city, I am trying to append the longitude and latitude values.

So for example, Fremont in the trie would look like

**F->R->E->M->O->N->T->(latitude and longitude)**

I am able to successfully insert the values into the trie, but when i try to search for a specific city, the longitude and latitude values return as (null)

Here is my implementation

```
void readFile(){

              //the functions that deal with the trie
                struct trieNode *node = initializeTrie();
                trieInsert(node, place, longitude, latitude);
                getTrie(node, place);
                trieFree(node);
}

struct trieNode{
        char *longi;
        char *lat;
        struct trieNode *children[27];
        char value;
};

struct trieNode *initializeTrie(){
        struct trieNode *pNode = NULL;

        pNode = (struct trieNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct trieNode));
        if(pNode){
                pNode->longi = '\0';
                pNode->lat = '\0';
                pNode->value = '\0';
                memset(pNode->children, 0, sizeof(pNode->children));
        }

        return pNode;
}


void trieFree(struct trieNode *root){
        int i;
        if(root){
                for(i = 0; i<= 26; i++){
                        trieFree(root->children[i]);
                }
        }
        free(root);
}

int trieInsert(struct trieNode *node, char *key, char *longitude, char *latitude){
        struct trieNode *parent = node;
        //printf("Longi: %s", longitude);
        //printf(" ");
        //printf("Latitude: %s \n", latitude);
        if(key){
                int index = 0;
                int i = 0;

                if(node){
                        while(key[i] != '\0'){
                                int indexVal = convertLetterToIndex(key[i]);
                                if(!parent->children[indexVal]){
                                        parent->children[indexVal] = initializeTrie();
                                        parent->children[indexVal]->value = key[i];
                                }
                                parent = parent->children[indexVal];
                                i++;
                        }

                        int longitudeLen = strlen(longitude);
                        int latitudeLen = strlen(latitude);

                        node->longi = malloc(longitudeLen + 1);
                        strncpy(node->longi, longitude, longitudeLen + 1);
                        node->longi[longitudeLen] = '\0';
                        //printf("Longi: %s", node->longi);
                        node->lat = malloc(latitudeLen + 1);
                        strncpy(node->lat, latitude, latitudeLen + 1);
                        node->lat[latitudeLen] = '\0';
                        //printf("Lati: %s \n", node->lat);
                        //free(node->longi);
                        //free(node->lat);
                }
        }


}

 //function to print the long and lat values based on the city
void getTrie(struct trieNode *root, char *key){
        struct trieNode *pNode = root;
        //bool flag = false;
        if(!key){
            printf("Not found \n");
        }

        if(!root){
                printf("Not found \n");
        }
        int i = 0;
        while(key[i] != '\0'){
                int indexVal = convertLetterToIndex(key[i]);
                if(!pNode->children[indexVal]){
                        printf("Not found \n");
                }

                pNode = pNode->children[indexVal];
                i++;
        }

        printf("Longitude: %s", pNode->longi);
        printf(" ");
        printf("Latitude: %s \n", pNode->lat);


}
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems which will result in the behavior you describe. I think [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful. Also, take a look at [How to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Several other problems: `pNode->longi = '\0';` initializes not an empty string, but initializes `longi` to NULL, basically "no string at all". You do not have `return`s in `getTrie` after "Not found" errors.

Comment: @yeputons but i do have the print statements in the getTrie function

Comment: You do, but there is no `return` after them, so execution is continued, which leads to undefined behavior because your code may read from null pointers.

Comment: @yeputons i left that function as a void, you also mentioned pNode->longi = '\0' being incorrect, what should it be initialized too

Comment: `return` is also used for exiting the function before its end. Right now, if node is not found in the tree, you can see several notifications about that or your program may crash because it tries to access pointer which points to null. E.g. if `root` is null, then your program will print `Not found` and then it _may_ crash when trying to read `pNode->children`

Comment: @yeputons I see, do you think the issue is with pNode->longi = '\0'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135829/discussion-between-yeputons-and-rrp).

Comment: `pNode->longi = '\0'` is really wrong. `pNode->longi` is a `char*`, while `'\0'` is a `char`.

Comment: Same goes for `pNode->lat = '\0'`.

Comment: You must be able to realize that, since you're also doing `pNode->value = '\0'`, where `value` is a `char`.

Comment: @barakmanos would this be the right way pNode->lat = NULL

Comment: @barakmanos ignore the last comment

Answer (score 0):

First of all `longi` and `lat` are of type `char *`, not `char` as `value`, so initialization

```
   pNode->longi = '\0';
   pNode->lat = '\0';
   pNode->value = '\0';
```

looks not so right.

It rather should be

```
   pNode->longi = NULL;
   pNode->lat = NULL;
   pNode->value = '\0';
```

(I do not want to ask why `value` is only one character - it is special way of data representation)

The next point for attention is using `strncpy` and `strlen` functions.

When you function `trieInsert` receive pointers to char you should check them as `if(longitude != NULL)` before using in expressions like `strlen(longitude)` and `strncpy(node->longi, longitude, longitudeLen + 1)`. And of course, the logic with pointer must be like:

- define pointer and init it with NULL;
- allocate memory with `malloc` or any other function for allocation (C standard dynamic memory allocation function return a null pointer if fail to allocate);
- check the value of pointer and use it after `if( p != NULL)` or `if( p )`.

That is some kind of good practice.

Comment: So the last bit is for good coding style right, just want to make sure if there isn't any error in that bit because i was able to print out the values for node->longi and node->lat. Which tells me that the values are being populated in the trie